# C# String Remove First 2 Object in a JSON.Stringify

Tags: c#, json, string

I have an MVC controller that accepts a json stringify object that looks like this:

```
[{\"name\":\"Name\",\"value\":\"1\"},
 {\"name\":\"Mobile\",\"value\":\"2\"},
 {\"name\":\"Gender\",\"value\":\"Male\"},
 {\"name\":\"Birthdate\",\"value\":\"2016-07-13\"},
 {\"name\":\"Address\",\"value\":\"3\"}]
```

And I want to remove the first 2 objects using a string function available in c# to look like this:

```
[{\"name\":\"Gender\",\"value\":\"Male\"},
 {\"name\":\"Birthdate\",\"value\":\"2016-07-13\"},
 {\"name\":\"Address\",\"value\":\"3\"}]`
```

How can I do this in the most simple way?

Comment: @M.Schena im looking for a way to do this without having to parse it back to json and using just string functions in c#

Comment: ok, made you a sample using only string functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using string-functions you could do following:

```
string s = "[{\"name\":\"Name\",\"value\":\"1\"}, {\"name\":\"Mobile\",\"value\":\"2\"}, {\"name\":\"Gender\",\"value\":\"Male\"}, {\"name\":\"Birthdate\",\"value\":\"2016-07-13\"}, {\"name\":\"Address\",\"value\":\"3\"}]";
string[] splitted = s.Split('{');
s = s.Replace("{" + splitted[1], "");
s = s.Replace("{" + splitted[2], "");
```

output:

```
[{"name":"Gender","value":"Male"}, 
{"name":"Birthdate","value":"2016-07-13"}, 
{"name":"Address","value":"3"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it will work.

```
var jArr =  JArray.Parse(json);

jArr.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>()
              .Where(p => p.Name == "Name" || p.Name == "Mobile")
              .ToList()
              .ForEach(att=>att.Remove());

var newJson = jArr.ToString();
```

OR

```
var jType = new[] { new{Gender="", Birthdate="", Address=""} };
var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                     JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, jType));
```